# Getting jQuery 'start with' selector to work with constructed Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click

I have

```
function librarytech(humanity,food,wood,metal,wealth)
{
this.humanity=humanity;
this.food=food;
this.wood=wood;
this.metal=metal;
this.wealth=wealth;
}
```

Then I construct some:

```
var library_science1=new librarytech(0,200,200,0,0);
var library_science2=new librarytech(0,4000,0,0,4000);
var library_science3=new librarytech(0,30000,0,0,30000);
```

I then have this .click function:

```
$("[id^='library_']").click(function() {
if (humanity >= this.humanity){

humanity -= this.humanity;
food -= this.food;
wood -= this.wood;
metal -= this.metal;
wealth -= this.wealth;

}});
```

Where the relavent HTML looks like:

```
<span id="library_science1"></span>
<span id="library_science2"></span>
<span id="library_science3"></span>
```

Yet it does not work, and I receive no errors I can see :/ Any suggestions? (The variable 'Humanity' is above 0 in these cases so it should be working?

Comment: `this` is conflicting inside of that click event i think, just assign the current class object to some other variable and then try.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the distinction between DOM elements and JavaScript variables. Write your logic first, *then* hook it into the DOM using event listeners.

Comment: can you create a working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: `this` inside click handler has nothing to do with `librarytech` objects.

Comment: @dfsq How then could I ensure that the 'this' inside the click handler refers to 1) a librarytech object, or 2) the ID of the span element I click on.

Comment: How do you create these spans? ID of the span is `this.id`.

Comment: @dfsq The span elements are not created via JS, they are hard-coded in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use an array:

DOM:

```
<ul id="libraries-science">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
function librarytech(humanity,food,wood,metal,wealth)
{
    this.humanity=humanity;
    this.food=food;
    this.wood=wood;
    this.metal=metal;
    this.wealth=wealth;
}

var librariesScience = [];
librariesScience.push(new librarytech(0,200,200,0,0));
librariesScience.push(new librarytech(0,4000,0,0,4000));
librariesScience.push(new librarytech(0,30000,0,0,30000));

$('ul#libraries-science > li').click(function () {
    var libraryScience = librariesScience[$(this).index()];
    // do your stuff here
});
```